# Intellij cannot resolve H2 variables

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, h2

I have an SQL file in IntelliJ that is configured to use the H2 dialect. When I define a variable, I get a warning that it cannot be resolved. This would make sense if using something like SQL Server dialect that supports the `DECLARE` keyword, but it is my understanding that variables are declared and assigned in H2 with `SET`.

[image]

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.2.5

**UPDATE**
I do have a SQL Server Database set as the Data Source of the module where the SQL file is located so that I can use it to resolve table and column names using the actual backend schema. When I `Alt+Enter` on the warning I have the option of setting the SQL Resolution Scopes, where my only option is my defined Data Source. So it would seem that it is only looking to resolve variables from the Data Source of the module. This doesn't fit my use case because for testing I am using an in memory H2 database.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Reported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7474